# Trying to delete npm-cache folder

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, directory

What would happen if I delete `npm-cache` `C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache`? Is it safe to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe so. npm-cache is just a way to save time and network bandwidth, just like a web browser's cache.

For those reasons, it might get repopulated when you do an `npm install` command.

Just to be on the safe side, however, instead of deleting, move the folder, rename the folder to something like ”npm-cache-archive-2023_04_23”, or zip it to somewhere so you can restore if necessary, then do normal operations (including `npm install` on whatever you're working on) to make sure before you do anything that would be a pain to recover. I've used it to get python on my machine when I was having company firewall issues getting it through normal channels, for example. In that case, I **should** have been able to delete that folder except it was a required workaround for something *else* that wasn't working the way *it* should!